# Is there any support from AgoraIO to build an Live Stream app using Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, live-streaming, agora.io

Is there any support from AgoraIO to build a Live Stream app using Android Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think right now Agora is still working on building sample projects with Jetpack Compose. Refer to the link to get an idea of how to use Jetpack Compose with the Agora Android UIKit.
https://github.com/Meherdeep/RTE-2021/tree/main/Android

Answer (score 1):

**Reply from Agora:**

Right now Agora is working on building sample projects with Jetpack Compose. But in the meanwhile, you can have a look at this repo that shows how to use Jetpack Compose with the Agora Android UIKit.

https://github.com/Meherdeep/RTE-2021/tree/main/Android

[image]